# Magento Update to 2.3.3 backend after login Specified invalid parent id Magento_Analytics

Tags: magento2, upgrade, composer, setup, magento2.3.3

i have a problem while upgrading Magento from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3. The update works fine and i have all done which mentioned here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html

After it, Magento Backend dont work correctly. The Loginform can be loaded but after login there comes an error:

> There has been an error processing your request
>
> Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>
> Error log record number: 1078057989546

The Erorr Log says:

> {"0":"Specified invalid parent id (Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence)","1":"#1 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callParent('getResult', array(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000005d9d073500000000399c9a80#)) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]\n#2 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000005d9d073500000000399c9a80#) called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]\n#3 Magento\Backend\Model\Menu\Builder\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getResult', array(&Magento\Backend\Model\Menu#000000005d9d073500000000399c9a80#), array(array('SetupMenuBuilder'))) called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Menu/Builder/Interceptor.php:26]........

i dont really know why, when i switch to 2.3.2 it works fine. Frontend works in both Versions fine, only backend in 2.3.3 have this issue. Update done with composer.

Do someone knows how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it may be possible that you have disabled **`Magento_Analytics`** module for some reason.

So for that please check here in config file you can see below result for `Magento_Analytics` this module..

> app/etc/config.php

```
'Magento_Analytics' => 0,
```

Because of that you are getting this error after upgrading Magento `v2.3.2` to `v2.3.3`. Magento added one more Adminhtml Menu in `Magento_Reports` which is **"Business Intelligence"**.

Here you can check this new menu added and they have added with the parent of "Magento_Reports"

> vendor/magento/module-analytics/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence" title="Business Intelligence" translate="title" module="Magento_Analytics"
             sortOrder="90" parent="Magento_Reports::report" resource="Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence" />
        <add id="Magento_Analytics::advanced_reporting" title="Advanced Reporting" translate="title" module="Magento_Analytics"
             sortOrder="10" parent="Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence" action="analytics/reports/show"
             target="_blank" resource="Magento_Analytics::advanced_reporting" />
        <add id="Magento_Analytics::bi_essentials" title="BI Essentials" translate="title" module="Magento_Analytics"
             sortOrder="20" parent="Magento_Analytics::business_intelligence" action="analytics/biessentials/signup"
             target="_blank" resource="Magento_Analytics::bi_essentials" />
    </menu>
</config>
```

**Solution :**

- So now Enable this Analytics module using below command or change from `0` to `1` in `config.php` file..

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Analytics
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will helpful to you!

Comment: Hey Kishan, i have now activated the Analytics and startet the update. Now Backend works fine. Just got trouble with a custom module but i can handle it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: That's Great! You can accept my answer and upvote. :) Happy to help you. :)

Comment: Done, thank you so much!

Comment: You're always welcome Buddy.

Answer (score 2):

Magento latest version have introduced another new analytic module named: `Yotpo_Yotpo` which depends on `Magento_Analytics`

So, along with other analytic modules, you also need to disable this `Yotpo_Yotpo`

```
bin/magento module:disable Yotpo_Yotpo -c
bin/magento seutp:di:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kishan's answer is correct however a compile is needed rather than a cache flush and a cache clean. With upgrade a cache clean is performed anyway.

There is also a likelihood that generated code can't be deleted.

Optional, if below does not work:

```
rm -fr magento/generated/code/Magento
```

Enable module, upgrade and compile:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Analytics
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:d:c
```